# Jquery modalpopupextender hiding in contentplaceholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

On default.aspx page that created by using a master page has a content place holder. And there is a modalpopupextender in that placeholder. I am tring to reach modalpopupextender with jquery and close it by pushing ESC keyboard button. I have tried these;

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
    $find('#<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>').hide(); // doesnt work !!!
        $find('<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>').hide(); // doesnt work !!!
        $find('ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID').hide(); // doesnt work !!!
    $find('ModalPopupExtender1').hide(); // doesnt work !!!

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$find('modalpopup').hide();
```

Assuming that  'modalpopup' is BehaviorID

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>

Comment: Sorry, I checked your code by using my BehaviorID, but this time the error says the object null or undefined

Comment: I am really sorry, the problem is reasoned by BehaviorID, your last code work fine. thank you